# How can I add sounds and a scoreboard to my tic tac toe site?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have an assignment that I have mostly done. It is coding a tic tac toe game using Javascript. But the two big things I cannot figure out how to do are to add a working scoreboard to the site that will increment wins and ties, and adding a sound that plays when someone wins and a different sound for when there is a tie game. I really need help. I'm so confused as to what to do. I've looked for solutions, but I can't see how any of the ones I've found work with my specific case. I'm just getting really frustrated with the whole thing and I'm tired of staring at this stupid code.

My HTML code is here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <audio src="../sounds/win.mp3" id="win"></audio>
    <audio src="../sounds/fail.mp3" id="tie"></audio>
    
    <head>
        <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="startGame();">
        <h2 id="game-message">Tic Tac Toe</h2>
        <div id="game-board"></div>
        <table id="scoreboard">
            <tr>
                <th>Player 1</th>
                <th>Player 2</th>
                <th>Ties</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="scores">
                <td class="score" id="p1score">
                    0
                </td>
                <td class="score" id="p2score">
                    0
                </td>
                <td class="score" id="tiescore">
                    0
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id=button><button id="playAgain" onclick="startGame();">Play Again?</button></div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my Javascript code:

```
var markers = ["X", "O"];
var players = [];
players[0] = prompt("Enter player one:");
players[1] = prompt("Enter player two:");
var totals = [];
var winCodes = [7,56,73,84,146,273,292,448];
var gameOver = false;
var whoseTurn = 0;
var p1Score = 0;
var p2Score = 0;
var win = new Audio('../sounds/success.mp3');
var tie = new Audio('../sounds/fail.mp3');

function startGame()
{
    var counter = 1;
    var innerDivs = "";
    for (i = 1; i <=3; i++)
    {
        innerDivs += '<div id="row-' + i + '">';
        
        for (j = 1; j <=3; j++)
        {
            innerDivs += '<div onclick="playGame(this,' + counter + ');"></div>';
            counter *=2;
        }

        innerDivs += '</div>';
    }

    document.getElementById("game-board").innerHTML = innerDivs;
    totals = [0, 0];
    gameOver = false;
    document.getElementById("game-message").innerText = "It's " + players[whoseTurn] + "'s Turn";
}

function playGame(clickedDiv, divValue)
{
    if (!gameOver)
    {
        //add x or o
        clickedDiv.innerText = markers[whoseTurn];

        //increment total for possible win
        totals[whoseTurn] += divValue;

        //call isWin() function
        if (isWin())
        {
            document.getElementById("game-message").innerText = players[whoseTurn] + " Wins!";
        }
        else if (gameOver)
            {
                document.getElementById("game-message").innerText = "Game Over, Man!";
            }
        else
        {
        //toggle player turn
        if (whoseTurn) whoseTurn = 0; else whoseTurn = 1;

        //prevent clicking same div again
        clickedDiv.onclick = "";

        //toggle message to display next player
        document.getElementById("game-message").innerText = "It's " + players[whoseTurn] +"'s turn";
        }
    }
}
//win code logic
function isWin()
{
    for (i = 0; i < winCodes.length; i++)
    {
        if ((totals[whoseTurn] & winCodes[i]) == winCodes[i]) { gameOver = true; return true; }        
    }

    if (totals[0] + totals[1] == 511) {gameOver = true;}

    return false;

}

var playSound = function()
{
    if (isWin() = true)
    {
        win.play();
    }
    if (gameOver = true)
    {
        tie.play();
    };
    playSound();
}
```

The last bit on the Javascript code was my attempt at making the audio work based off of an answer I saw to somebody else who seemed to have a similar issue, but it doesn't work for me.

As far as the scoreboard goes, I don't even know where to start.

ETA: I have tried moving the win.play() into the isWin function like this:

```
if ((totals[whoseTurn] & winCodes[i]) == winCodes[i]) { gameOver = true; win.play(); return true; }
```

It doesn't work, either.

Comment: If your scoreboard only needs to keep local scores, you can use localStorage, otherwise you're going to need a backend / db

Answer (score 0):

Your playSound function won't work, as you're calling it within itself. Call playSound() elsewhere, when the game is over within the isWin() function

Comment: I've tried adding in there, but it's not working. If I just add it to overall isWin function brackets it doesn't play sound and also has the added bonus of making every click an X, instead of alternating X O X O. Honestly I'm about at the point that I'm just going to turn it in and take the hit on my grade. I've been staring at this for two days and I'm about to throw my computer at the wall.

Comment: You got this. One other this is, in playSound, you have if isWin() = true, it should be if isWin() === true, same for the gameOver check.

Even better, you can jut do if(isWin()) {} or if(gameOver) {}

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, either. I'm just turning it in. If I look at this anymore I'm going to start crying. I'm so frustrated right now.

Comment: @WastelandSniper I would highly recommend, if you have not already, trying to get some time to talk to someone at your institute. There should be a support network of instructors, tutors and technical staff that are in a position to offer guidance (_not_ **give** you an answer, but guidance). If you are interested in web development, particulary from a creative standpoint, I would also checkout https://p5js.org and Dan Shiffman's Coding Train Series. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTWrWM1UsnA